# Connect and present data from two different tables in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to easily present data from two different tables (classes). I have an `Environment` class with all the environments details and a `Changes` class which contain history changes on all my environments.

My view is currently showing all my `Environment` details. I want to add to this view the last change been made on each environment (e.g last modified by: `User`).

My `models.py` look like this:

```
class System(models.Model):
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    system_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    system_clusters = models.ManyToManyField(Cluster, blank=True)
    system_owner = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.system_name

class Changes(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    change_reason = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date
```

At first, i though to pass a dictionary to my template with the `system` as a key and a `change` as a value:

```
last_changes = {}
change =   Changes.objects.filter(cluster__in=s.system_clusters.all()).order_by('-id')[0]
last_changes[s.system_id] = change.change_reason
```

Even though it partially works (I still trying to parse the dict in my template), I feel like this is not the right approach for the task.

I'm hoping to reach a result where I can just call `system.last_change` in my template. Can I add another field for `System` class that will point to his `last_change` in the `Changes` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method on System to return the last change for an item:

```
def last_change(self):
    return self.changes_set.order_by('-date').first()
```

Now you can indeed call `system.last_change` in the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew there should be something simple for that.
I didn't understand how self.changes_set.order_by('-date').first() will return the last change from Changes table. I just used the following instead:
return Changes.objects.filter(cluster__in=self.system_clusters.all()).order_by('-id')[0]

Thanks again.